# Calculate mean, ratio and pvalue on subset for different colums

Tags: r, dataframe, math

```
mydf <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
                 id   col1     col2     col3     col4
                   N  1        8        5        10
                   N  3        7        4        20
                   N  5        6        3        40
                   N  1        8        5        10
                   N  3        7        4        20
                   N  5        6        3        40
                   F  10       1        2        5
                   F  10       1        2        5
                   F  10       1        2        5

                 ")
```

Output

```
          col1     col2     col3     col4
Mean_N
Mean_F
Ratio_N_F
Pvalue_NvsF
```

I can calculate p-value by:

```
lapply(m[-1], function(x) t.test(x ~ m$id))
```

I could use `melt()` to calculate the mean

How can I put all together in a final data frame?

Comment: How is ratio defined? If N / F rows, both need to be same length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an `rbind` across separate aggregations calls. Below assumes ratio, *Ratio_N_F*, is the ratio of column means.

```
outdf <- rbind(
  Mean_N = aggregate(.~id, mydf[mydf$id=='N',], FUN=mean)[-1],
  Mean_F = aggregate(.~id, mydf[mydf$id=='F',], FUN=mean)[-1],
  Ratio_N_F = aggregate(.~id, mydf[mydf$id=='N',], FUN=mean)[-1] / 
                 aggregate(.~id, mydf[mydf$id=='F',], FUN=mean)[-1],
  Pvalue_NvsF = sapply(mydf[-1], function(x) t.test(x ~ mydf$id)$p.value)
)

outdf
#                     col1         col2       col3        col4
# Mean_N      3.000000e+00 7.000000e+00 4.00000000 23.33333333
# Mean_F      1.000000e+01 1.000000e+00 2.00000000  5.00000000
# Ratio_N_F   3.000000e-01 7.000000e+00 2.00000000  4.66666667
# Pvalue_NvsF 2.093883e-04 1.523397e-05 0.00276496  0.02178842
```